# groupby in javascript using ArrayObject.reducer()

Tags: javascript, reduce

I found the following code it here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

I was wondering if could one can explain why we need the second {} in the reduce function? Is it an empty object to put the result in?

```
var _groupBy = function(objectArray, property) {
    return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
        var key = obj[property];
        if (!acc[key]) {
          acc[key] = [];
        }
        acc[key].push(obj);
        return acc;
    }, {});
};
```

Comment: That `{}` is the `initialValue` mentioned in the link you posted -- `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])`. It's the first value of `acc` after that `acc` is the value returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of reduce is your starting point. It will be the value of the `acc` argument in the function that is passed in as the first argument of reduce during the first iteration of processing.

Comment: oh I see - for each obj on ObjectArray once it returns acc, it will be added to that {} ?? interesting .. tnx

Comment: no problem, the most challenging part of using reduce, is remembering to return something in that first function. And debugging these things can be quite tiresome sometimes. :)